# How to persist a Celery queue in a database

Tags: database, queue, celery, resume

Celery documentation under [transient queues](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#using-transient-queues) states:

> Queues created by Celery are persistent by default. This means that the broker will write messages to disk to ensure that the tasks will be executed even if the broker is restarted.

With the additional concern of **ephemeral** file systems, how can I ensure that the queue resumes after the host restart and clears the file system?

Or similarly, how can I persist a celery queue to a database?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use a broker that has built-in high-availability. Redis in the clustered mode is a good option, same goes for SQS or RabbitMQ.

Comment: Does that mean that the application needs to be replicated over several nodes? While this sounds more performant, I am looking for the simplest possible solution, hence was thinking of persisting the queue in a database.

Comment: You may have one or more nodes for your workers - that is absolutely fine. We are talking about the broker here, not the workers.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the broker, e.g. Redis, keeps a copy in memory, runs in a separate service, then if the celery node where the queue is persisted on disk goes down, the broker will have kept the copy in memory and would re-write the queue once the celery node is up again. The high-availability of the broker just diminishes the likelihood that both celery node and broker are down. Do I get this correctly?

Comment: In the clustered mode, the data that Redis keeps in memory is replicated on all nodes, so in the case one node crashes, the other node becomes a master and carries on. HA of the broker diminishes the likelihood that you will lose tasks. Even if ALL nodes go down, and you run new ones, they will start picking what is in the queue to run. It has nothing to do with the nodes (workers) though. They have their own lifecycle.